# Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using [nativescript-vue-router](https://github.com/emiliogrv/nativescript-vue-router) to handle routing in my nativescript-vue app.

I had done manual routing before, but I'm using this package so can access the `beforeEach` method.

I'm trying to get the list of routes and loop through them but I'm unable to access `$router.options.routes`

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
```

This is what I'm basically trying to do

```
this.$router.options.routes.forEach(route => {
                this.items.push({
                    name: route.name,
                    path: route.path,
                    icon: route.icon,
                    component: route.component
                })
            })
```

However, if I access `$router.push('Home')` directly in the markup, it works and I can access that specific route.

My code is almost identical to the documentation, except my `app.js` is a bit different since I'm using RadDrawer

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue"
import App from "./components/App"
//import routes from '~/router'
import router from './router'
import { store } from './store/store'
import Home from "./components/Home"
import DrawerContent from "./components/DrawerContent"
import RadSideDrawer from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/vue"

Vue.use(RadSideDrawer);

//Vue.prototype.$routes = routes

import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools'
Vue.use(VueDevtools)

Vue.config.silent = (TNS_ENV === 'production');

Vue.registerElement('CheckBox', () => require('nativescript-checkbox').CheckBox, {
    model: {
        prop: 'checked',
        event: 'checkedChange'
    }
});

new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    render (h) {
        return h(
          App,
          [
            h(DrawerContent, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
            h(Home, { slot: 'mainContent' })
          ]
        )
      }
  }).$start();
```

This is `router/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'

import NSVueRouter from 'nativescript-vue-router-ns'

import Home from "../components/Home";
import Browse from "../components/Browse";
import Featured from "../components/Featured";
import Search from "../components/Search";
import Settings from "../components/Settings";
import Tasks from "../components/Tasks";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import Logout from "../components/Logout";

Vue.use(NSVueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        icon: "\uf015",
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/browse',
        name: 'Browse',
        icon: '\uf25a',
        component: Browse,
        meta: {
            auth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/featured',
        name: 'Featured',
        icon: '\uf005',
        component: Featured
    },
    {
        path: '/search',
        name: 'Search',
        icon: '\uf002',
        component: Search
    },
    {
        path: '/settings',
        name: 'Settings',
        icon: '\uf013',
        component: Settings
    },
    {
        path: '/tasks',
        name: 'Tasks',
        icon: '\uf0ae',
        component: Tasks,
        meta: {
            auth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        icon: '\uf007',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            guest: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/logout',
        name: 'Logout',
        icon: '\uf007',
        component: Logout,
        meta: {
            auth: true
        }
    }
];

const router = new NSVueRouter({
    //ignoreSame, // <-- Optional. Will set if reject or accept navigate to same current component.
    routes,
    /* eslint-disable-next-line no-undef  */
    verbose: TNS_ENV !== 'production' // <-- Optional. Will output the warnings to console.
});

export default router
```

Please note that if I uncomment `ignoreSame` I get an error `Undefined variable ignoreSame`

And this is the markup in `DrawerContent.vue` where I can access each route individually like so

```
<GridLayout
        columns="auto, *"
        class="sidedrawer-list-item"
        @tap="$router.push('Tasks')">
    <Label col="0" text="\uf015" class="fa"></Label>
    <Label col="1" text="Tasks" class="p-r-10"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

But I want to get all the routes in an array and loop through them, like so

```
<GridLayout
        columns="auto, *"
        :class="'sidedrawer-list-item' + (selectedPage === page.name ? ' selected': '')"
        v-for="(page, i) in pages"
        :key="i"
        @tap="goToPage(page.component)">
    <Label col="0" :text="page.icon" class="fa"></Label>
    <Label col="1" :text="page.name" class="p-r-10"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

EDIT: even when I goto `router/index.js` and `console.log(router.routes)` I get `undefined`

Comment: what is output of `this.$router.options`?

Comment: It returns `undefined` but `this.$router` returns the following `{ back: { [Function: back] [length]: 0, [name]: 'back' }, push: { [Function: push] [length]: 0, [name]: 'push' }, pushClear: { [Function: pushClear] [length]: 1, [name]: 'pushClear' } }`

Comment: It doesn't have `options` property.

Comment: I believe it does. https://github.com/emiliogrv/nativescript-vue-router/blob/master/index.js

Comment: You are not using classic vue-router (`import NSVueRouter from 'nativescript-vue-router-ns'`)

Comment: @mare96 from nativescript-vue documentation `Currently, integration with Vue Router is unsupported. Until the team resolves the issue, please use manual routing.`

Comment: How is `pages` being assigned to the `routes` array in your second `GridLayout` example?

Comment: @LenJoseph that's from old code where I created my own router. I had the routes stored in a computed array and then I looped through it in the GridLayout. At the moment, I hadn't reached that point to take care of the array and loop because I can't even access the $routes. My hope would be to store the routes in an array once I'm able to retrieve them and pass them to the GridLayout.

Comment: Can you write an iterator that does `for (route in $router) {}` and interpolate the results in your markup?

Comment: @LenJoseph `v-for="(page, i) in $router"` returns `back`, `clear`, and `pushClear`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define prototype in router/index.js right under the declaration "Vue.prototype.$router = router;" this will make the instance available in any component.

```
const router = new NSVueRouter({
    //ignoreSame, // <-- Optional. Will set if reject or accept navigate to same current component.
    routes,
    /* eslint-disable-next-line no-undef  */
    //verbose: TNS_ENV !== 'production' // <-- Optional. Will output the warnings to console.
})

Vue.prototype.$router = router;
```